# Button is not adding text to the beginning of a text box, but at the end

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Private Sub plusMinusButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles plusMinusButton.Click

        If answerBox.Text <> "0" Then
            If answerBox.Text.StartsWith("-") Then

                answerBox.Text = answerBox.Text.Replace("-", String.Empty)
            Else

                'answerBox.Text.Reverse()
                'answerBox.AppendText("-")
                answerBox.Text = answerBox.Text.Insert(0, "-")
                'answerBox.Text.Reverse()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

This code is supposed to make the number in the text box either positive or negative, depending on if there is a "-" in front of the number or not. But, whenever I run this code, and I input any number other than "0" and I click on the plusMinusButton, the result I get in the text box (answerBox) is something like 1- instead of -1. Now, I changed the code to this, and I got the result I wanted:

```
Private Sub plusMinusButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles plusMinusButton.Click

        If answerBox.Text <> "0" Then
            If answerBox.Text.EndsWith("-") Then

                answerBox.Text = answerBox.Text.Replace("-", String.Empty)
            Else

                answerBox.Text.Reverse()
                answerBox.AppendText("-")
                'answerBox.Text = answerBox.Text.Insert(0, "-")
                answerBox.Text.Reverse()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens with a bigger number "123"? Is there any other relevant code? (Why the VBA tag?)

Comment: The same thing happens with bigger numbers. **P.S.:** I didn't know that the vba tag wasn't equivalent to vb.net. Sorry if that misled you.

Comment: Is this a practice example? If not, it would be best to parse to integer and then multiply by `-1`

Comment: I tried your first code and it's working as expected.

Comment: The code you posted in the first block worked.  Are you doing something in the TextChanged event?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a variable to hold the value.

When you add or minus the value, make it with the integer variable, then after the operation you put the value of variable in your textbox